# When is $SL_1$ of a quaternion division algebra perfect?

Tags: quaternion-algebras

Let $F$ be a field, let $a,b \in F$ and let $\mathcal A:= \left(\frac{a,b}{F}\right)$ be the quaternion algebra over $F$ determined by the relations
$$
i^2 = a, \quad j^2 = b, \quad k = ij = -ji.
$$
Denote by ${\rm SL}_1(\mathcal A)$ the group of elements of reduced norm $1$ in $\mathcal A$. I am looking for conditions which ensure that ${\rm SL}_1(\mathcal A)$ is perfect.

I am particularly interested in the case where $F$ is a number field, and $\mathcal A$ is a division algebra. In this situation, ${\rm SL}_1(\mathcal A)$ is an algebraic group over $\mathbb Q$, and for my purposes, it would suffice to conclude that this group does not admit any non-trivial $\mathbb Q$-characters.

Comment: By $\mathbb Q$-characters, you mean characters that are algebraic functions defined over $\mathbb Q$? This is not very hard, and you can base change to $\mathbb C$ to check this. Or something else?

Comment: For any central simple algebra $A$ of dimension $n^2$ over any field $k$ with $n>1$, the $k$-group ${\rm{SL}}_1(A)$ becomes ${\rm{SL}}_n$ over a finite extension of $k$ that splits $A$, so perfectness in the sense of algebraic groups is immediately reduced to the case of ${\rm{SL}}_n$ that is "classical" (and even reduces in turn to the case of ${\rm{SL}}_2$ that is truly classical).  Since you mention trying to use absence of non-trivial characters it seems you already know the group is reductive, but how do you know that? Any method proving that almost surely proves it is even semisimple.

Comment: Another remark about the absence of characters: if $\mathcal{A}$ is a quadratic division algebra, it splits over a quadratic extension $L$ of $\mathbf{Q}$. A maximal torus is given by the norm 1 elements of the Weil restriction from L to $\mathbf{Q}$ of the multiplicative algebraic group over $L$. This maximal torus has no character over $\mathbf{Q}$ (see Platonov-Rapinchuk, algebraic groups and number theory, example in section 2.1 about what they call "the norm torus"). So maximal tori already have no character. Another way to phrase this is "${\rm SL}_1(\mathcal{A})$ is anisotropic".

Comment: @thierrystulemeijer, but absence of non-trivial characters on a subgroup does not imply their absence on the group.  Of course it's different for a *maximal torus* in a *reductive* group, but, as @‍nfdc23 points out, knowing that $\mathrm{SL}_1(\mathcal A)$ is (the group of $\mathbb Q$-points of) a reductive group is much of the battle already.  (Also, I think it's not usual to call a reductive group anisotropic if it has an anisotropic torus.  This would make any reductive $p$-adic group with anisotropic centre itself anisotropic.)

Comment: @LSpice thanks very much for your interesting corrections! I agree, and to reinforce your comment on my problematic implied definition of anisotropicity, using again the norm torus, ${\rm SL}_n$ over $k$ contains a maximal torus which is anisotropic as soon as k has a field extension of degree n.